# When does two curves do not intersect in the phase space

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

When can I say , that two curves in the phase space of the following equation never intersect:

> $x'=F(x,t)$

Where $x'= \frac{dx}{dt}$ and $F : \mathbb{R}^{3} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$.

The reason I am asking this is because when our lecturer talked about Poincare map and the Van Der Pol equations , she wanted to prove the following claim:

> Poincare map has one fixed point $y_0$, and for any $y \in \mathbb{R}^+$  we have that the limit of $P^ny$ as $n \to \infty$ is $y_0$

Where $P$ is Poincare map , and $P^n$ is poincare map composed wth itself $n$ times.

Before proving the claim she said that " $P $ is monotonic on $\mathbb{R}^+ $  and that we **can** conclude this frm the fact that curves do not intersect..." (the rest of the sentence is not really important but it was clear why it is true,but I couldn't understand why the curves do not intersect)

I will be happy if you could help me understand

Comment: Recall the existence and uniqueness of solutions of differential equations. If $F$ is at least $C^1$ in $x$ (one time differentiable with continuous derivative) then the equation $x'=F$ has a unique solution for a given initial condition $x(t_0)$. If two solutions were to intersect, that would mean that to a given initial condition (the point of intersection) correspond two orbits or solution curves. This contradicts unicity, and thus, it cannot happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understood (I also talked with some people about this):

Let $x_1 , x_2$ be two solutions to the ode.

$\exists T \in \mathbb{R} $  s.t.  $x_1(0) = x_2 (T)$ or $\forall T \in \mathbb{R} x_1(0) \neq x_2 (T)$ . Assuming $F$ is $C^1$ we can conclude from the uniqness theorem that we must have exactly one of the following:

1) The curves in the phase space of $x_1$ and $x_2$ do not intesect.

2) The curves in the phase space of $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the same curve.

If we have $\forall T \in \mathbb{R} x_1(0) \neq x_2 (T)$ , then of course we have (1) , elseways $\exists T \in \mathbb{R} $  s.t.  $x_1(0) = x_2 (T)$ , but in this case using uniqness theorem we can conclude that

$\forall t:$  $x_1(t) = x_2(T+t)$

Meaning the curves are equal (as sets)